# jquery get all input form elements including radio

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to notify users if they were leaving the form page with unsaved changes in it.

With the following script I am successfully retrieving all input fields except if radio field as been changed.

How can I also get the radio field?

**jQuery**

```
$(':input').each(function() { 
$(this).data('initialValue', $(this).val()); 
}); 

window.onbeforeunload = function(){ 
    var msg = 'Unsaved data presence'; 
    var isDirty = false; 

    $(':input').each(function () { 
        if($(this).data('initialValue') != $(this).val()){ 
            isDirty = true; 
        } 
    }); 

    if(isDirty == true){ 
        return msg; 
    } 
};
```

**HTML**

```
...
<fieldset class="radio btn-group btn-group-yesno" id="jform_params_admin">
    <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="1" name="jform[params][admin]" id="jform_params_admin0">
    <input type="radio" value="0" name="jform[params][admin]" id="jform_params_admin1">
    <label for="jform_params_admin1" class="btn">No</label>
</fieldset>
<input type="text" size="40" class="inputbox" value="text" id="jform_params_text" name="jform[params][admin_text]">
...
```

Comment: where is data-initialValue in radio ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

1.Remove `initialValue` because you don't need it.

2.You can use the following **untested** code instead:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){ 
  var msg = 'Unsaved data presence'; 
  var isDirty = false; 

  $(':input').each(function () {
    var $e = $(this);
    if(($e.is(':checkbox') || $e.is(':radio')) && $e.prop('defaultChecked') != $e.prop('checked')) {
      isDirty = true;
    } else if($e.prop('defaultValue') != $e.val()) {
      isDirty = true;
    }
  }); 

  if(isDirty == true){ 
      return msg; 
  } 
};
```

**OLD**

Your code to check if the input changed is simply wrong. The problem is that radio and checkboxes do not change `value` when you check the checkbox/radoi. They change the `checked` attribute. You can fix it by adding some different code for checkbox/radios:

```
$(':input').each(function() { 
  $(this).data('initialValue', $(this).val()); 
}); 

$(':radio').each(function() { 
  $(this).data('initialValue', $(this).checked()); 
});
```

and later:

```
$(':input').each(function () {
    if($(this).data('initialValue') != $(this).val() || $(this).data('initialValue') != $(this).checked()){ 
        isDirty = true; 
    }
});
```

Comment: There's no need to loop and set `initialValue`, the dom objects already contain the relevant properties (`defaultValue` and `defaultChecked`), which can be used and tested against

Comment: I know that. But maybe he needs backwards compatibility?

Comment: @Robert Thank you. I will try it later. I am approaching this issue correctly or there is a more appropriate way of doing it?

Comment: As @billyonecan mentioned, you should use defaultValue/defaultChecked properties if possible.

Comment: @Robert I am newbie with jQuery. Could you please give me some example?

Comment: @Robert Every thing is working just fine. My only issue is how to also check drop-down `<select>`. Can you give me some clue?

Comment: You can use `selectedIndex` and `defaultSelected` see http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: @Robert Sorry to bother you again, but I am having trouble to get it working :( Could you please give me some example?

Comment: @Robert Could be like this? `code` $('select').each(function () { 
        var $e = $(this)[0];      
        if (!$e.options[$e.selectedIndex].defaultSelected) {
        isDirty = true;
    } `code`

Comment: Please open another question.